# jquery scrollable cloned divs

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools, scrollable, autoscroll

I just want to make a simple scrollable gallery on my front page. I followed instruction on http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/index.html. I am calling

```
$(".scrollable").scrollable({circular:true}).autoscroll({interval:5000});
```

on my scrollable div on document ready. I understand that circular creates two cloned divs, one at each part of the div list of items. When my page loads the first cloned div is in front, when the first scroll happens it scrolls for two divs... so skipping the first div which is actually the same as the cloned one, but a user can still see that one image was skipped. I checked working examples like http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/plugins-chain.htm and also some other sites that use the same functionality. I found out that on those pages the first div that is in row is the actual first div, not the clone. Why is it that the cloned div gets first in row on my page and not on others?

I googled for this issue but could not find anything useful but I understand this might be a dumb issue, but I have spent hours finding what is wrong without any results so please help me!

Comment: Perhaps something in your CSS?